# How to use Selenium to upload files to Google Drive?

Tags: selenium, web, selenium-webdriver, google-drive-api, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to automate the upload to Google Drive. However, after I select the "Upload File" div in my google drive and try to send file path to it. Nothing shows on my google drive. Did I find the wrong WebElement or it's something else. Please help me! Thank you! Below is the Java code. I only post the uploading part. I have initialized the drive before.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);  
// click the "New Button" and see the list of actions
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[aria-label=\"New\"]")).click();
// select the webelement for upload files
WebElement addNewFile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[3]/div/span[2]/span/div"));
action.moveToElement(addNewFile);
action.click();
// send the file path to the webelement
action.sendKeys("/home/path/to/file/file.pdf");
action.perform();
```

Comment: Doesn't the path to the file need to be the full path (e.g. starting a c:\, etc.)?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I was using Linux.

Comment: It looks like you are clicking the upload button and then trying to send the path to the dialog... you don't do that with Selenium. Don't click the upload button, just send the filepath to the INPUT type=file.

Comment: But I couldn't find the input type="file" in google drive html

Comment: I will get "no such element" error

Comment: Clicking on addNewFile opens an pop up window. Since selenium is a browser based tool it cannot handle OS windows. You can use an add-on like [AutoIT](https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html) for this task.